# How do I use C# queries on a prexisting database(SQLite database)?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I have run into a problem where my C# code is creating a whole new database instead of using a preexisting one. Then my program runs into errors where the program cannot find the table to insert the information even though the preexisting database has the table because the code itself is looking at the new table. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Finisar.SQLite;

namespace WestSlope
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
        //SQLiteDataAdapter sqlite_datareader;

        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=ClientLogDB.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

        //open conection
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        //create sql commands
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

        //Let SQLite command know query is known
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ASAM (ASAMone, ASAMtwo, ASAMthree, ASAMfour, ASAMLim, ASAMLimEX) VALUES ('Had to call', 'Reffered', 'Had to call', 'Watched', 1 , 'Injured legs');"
;

        //execute query
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();











        sqlite_conn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

What the code is supposed to do is when the user presses a button the program will save information to the preexisting database; but, as you can see the program is making a new database instead of using the preexisting one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new=false` in your connection string to use existing database file.
Following should be the connection string:

```
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=ClientLogDB.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
```